# Yii2 modal popup height issue

Tags: model, yii2, popup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnnhQ.png)

Can anyone tell me how can i put all the fields inside this popup so that popup size remain same.

Comment: add related code also.

Comment: I found the solution. just use:
<style>
#modalContent    /*id of your content div*/
{
    height:650px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. just use: 
 #modalContent /*id of your content div*/ { height:650px; overflow-y: auto; }